# Proving supremum of set $\left\{\frac{6n-5}{27n - 9n^2 - 20} \middle| n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$

Tags: calculus, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, supremum-and-infimum

> Prove that $\sup\left\{\frac{6n-5}{27n - 9n^2 - 20} \middle| n \in \mathbb{N}\right\} = 0.$

To prove that supremum of this set is indeed zero, I have to do the following:

1. Prove that $(\forall n \in \mathbb{N})\left(\frac{6n-5}{27n - 9n^2 - 20} \leq 0\right).$ Mine result is that this is true.
2. Prove that $(\forall \varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}^{+})(\exists n \in \mathbb{N})\left(\frac{6n-5}{27n - 9n^2 - 20} > -\varepsilon\right).$

I've got a problem with second statement. How shall I proceed?

Comment: 2. follows if you show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (6n-5)/(27n-9n^2-20)$ is zero, which should be doable with a bit of calculus knowledge.

Comment: @ec92 We can't use limits to prove it, unfortunately, just approximations using inequalities and algebraic manipulation.

Comment: The expression is $\geq n/(27n-9n^2)=1/(27-9n)$, is it clearer from here?

Comment: I forgot to add "eventually", that is for $n$ large enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write it as
$$\frac{ n\left( 6-\frac{5}{n} \right)  }{  -n^2\left( 9-\frac{27}{n}+\frac{20}{n^2}\right) }=-\frac{1}{n} \frac{6-\frac{5}{n}}{ 9-\frac{27}{n}+\frac{20}{n^2}}$$
and show that the second factor can be made arbitrarily close to $\frac{6}{9}$ when $n$ is big. In fact you just need to show that it is bounded, and then the first factor makes the product very close to zero when $n$ is large.